# Страница на несуществующем адресе

Tags: .htaccess

Вопрос заключается в выводе контента на несуществующей странице без переадресации (Без изменения адреса в строке). Например на site.ru/kmf2sp вывести страницу site.ru/index
И можно ли передать 'kmf2sp' как Get параметр для вывода (т.е. чтобы было site.ru/index?url=kmf2sp)

Предполагаю что это делается на .htaccess

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index?url=$1` но это и для site.ru/index будет работать, поэтому  сперва для индекса правило нужно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Нашел хороший пример и совместил с вашим примером. Итог таков:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index [L]

Answer (score 0):

Можно в `.htaccess` задать такой обработчик ошибки:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index?url=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Немного не то что нужно, но это тоже пригодится